# Find memory allocated within a method of java in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, tomcat8

Is there any known implementation to approximately calculate the memory allocated in a method to each variable, provided jvm has access to ThreadMXBean.

Or does tomcat provide any tools for the same?

> Method will be invoked from a HttpServlet in tomcat 8.